# How can TAS be calculated from indicated temperature and Mach number?

Tags: airspeed, temperature, e6b, mach-number

## Situation

I am working on programming my own E6B while I learn more about aviation, but I have run into some confusion. Two pairs of the equations are very similar except for using true or indicated temps based on which equation. If anyone has a Sporty's E6B, it is listed as Planned Mach # and Actual Mach # as well as Planned TAS and Actual TAS.

## Important Info

**The inputs for the Mach # formulas are as follows:**
Temp, Mach #

**While the output is:**
TAS

**The inputs for the TAS formulas are as follows:**
Pressure Altitude, Temp, CAS

**While the outputs are:**
TAS, Mach #, Density Altitude

"Planned" versions take "True Temp" according to the manual, while the "Actual" versions use "Indicated Temp". From what I can tell from research, True temp is known as SAT (Static) and Indicated would be RAT (Ram). I have also been told that there usually isn't a difference between the 2 unless you are over certain speeds... but I am thinking that maybe there is some form of temperature conversion that I need to do with the RAT/Indicated input. As you can see below, using the same inputs will provide slightly different outputs.

### Examples

**Planned Mach #** with Indicated Temp of 22C and Mach # of 0.33 provides a True Airspeed output of 221

**Actual Mach #** with Indicated Temp of 22C and Mach # of 0.33 provides a True Airspeed output of 218.6

## Where I'm at and have tried

I am able to calculate the correct answers when using True Temp but not Indicated. Currently, I've been trying to convert RAT to SAT with some math I found using a "recovery factor". I get quite close to the result that my Digital E6B but it is not the same result. I have used many different formulas from an AI I won't name... and overall I am just stumped. After a week of trying, I am going to ask this forum, which has helped me many times before.

## Does anyone have some insight on how to handle this and use the Indicated Temperature in these equations?

Comment: Does this [answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/15196/19) your question?

Comment: Does [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43998/how-to-convert-ias-cas-to-tas-up-to-mach-3), [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/60999/whats-the-formula-to-calculate-static-air-temperature) and [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15194/is-the-mach-number-shown-by-an-air-data-computer-considered-a-true-mach-number/15196#15196) answer your question?

Comment: How do you program an E6B?

Comment: @MichaelHall I am a Software Engineer, and I am developing an app that amongst other things, contains the equations you would have on a commercially available E6B... that's what I meant by that.

Comment: @sophit I ended up using one of the formulas in those which is also about halfway thru the DeltaLima answer below, so yes... kinda. Thank you for the links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TAS is Mach number ($M_a$) multiplied by the speed of sound ($a$).

$$\textrm{TAS}=M_a\cdot a$$

The speed of sound depends on the temperature of the (static) air $T_s$.

$$ a = \sqrt{\gamma  RT_s}$$

The relation between the measured total air temperature (or ram air temperature) and the static temperature is given by:

$$\frac{T_\mathrm{total}}{T_{s}}={1+\frac{\gamma -1}{2}M_a^2}$$

Since the measurement probe may not recover all the energy from the adiabatic heating, a correction factor is introduced:

$$\frac{T_\mathrm{total}}{T_{s}}={1+\frac{\gamma -1}{2}eM_a^2}$$

This 'recovery factor' $e$ is determined empirically for the temperature sensor used.

Putting it all together yields:

$$\textrm{TAS} = M_a \sqrt{\frac{\gamma R T_{\textrm{total}}}{1+\frac{\gamma -1}{2}eM_a^2}}$$

- The ratio of specific heats $\gamma$ is 1.4
- R, the specific gas constant is 287.052874 J K/kg

The formula is for SI units, so temperature should be in Kelvin [K], TAS will be given in meters per second [m/s]

Comment: I will review it and let you know how it goes... appreciate it

Comment: Thanks, @DeltaLima for the in-depth response. Currently, I am unsuccessful with this because after trying the formula you gave by hand, code, and calculator I get a TAS of 30 which I know is not right. I feel like there is nowhere on Earth where one-third of the speed of sound would be 30mph. 

I may be misunderstanding the answer you gave but will keep looking into this.

Comment: What units did you calculate with? The formulas are for SI units. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Oh, yeah definitely was not using those. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I have gotten to a point where a bit of rounding will basically line up with what I expect for the results. What I ended up doing is using the formula from above that discusses the "relation between" the 2 temps and doesn't use the recovery factor. 

I solved for static temp and threw the result into my original equation which I have been using when given True/Static temperature... I will mark this as answered, but I wanted to comment that I did not get here by using the very last equation in your answer.

Comment: @Bellarose143 when I put the numbers in, with e = 1 for a perfect temperature sensor, I get almost exactly what you have given in your example. (220.9 for the true temperature case, 218.6 for the indicated temperature case)

Comment: I'll try again with 1... I was using 0.98.